# I want to control progress bar

Tags: html

I want to control progress bar
using variable

Like exp bar in games

can I get some example sources??

Ex:
1. HP : 10/10    [----------] <--Progressbar
2. Attacked by Monster [HP - 3]
3. HP : 7/10     [-------   ]

Like this
Sorry for bad English

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. It would be helpful to see some the related code you've already written.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good example about that

```js
var percentage = 75;
$(".progressbar").animate({
   width: percentage + "%"
},1000);
```

```css
.container{
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #ebebeb;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.progressbar{
  width: 0%;
  height: 50px;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
<div class="progressbar">

</div>
</div>
```

I have even build a website with something like that: http://m-andi.comyr.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstrap progress bars and have a javascript var which then gets updated along with progress bar.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
  var health = 100;
</script>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Colored Progress Bars</h2>
  <p>The contextual classes colors the progress bars:</p>
  <div class="progress">
    <div id="healthId" class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:100%">
      Health
    </div>
  </div>
  <button onclick="attackHealth()">Attack</button>
  <script>
function attackHealth() {
  health = health - 7;
  document.getElementById("healthId").setAttribute("style", "width:" + health + "%");
}
  </script>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```